# User DataSet Editor

Tags: vb.net, dataset, strongly-typed-dataset

When the user clicks an "Edit" button on my form, I want a box to come up which allows the user to edit a DataTable in a strongly-typed DataSet.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I got your question right what you should do is just bind your table to your typed dataset and don't forget to supply the insert/delete/update statements to the table adapter.

Comment: i meant bind a grid to your typed data set table

Comment: I got that, but my data won't save (see main post).

Comment: I rolled back the edit to the original question, which you answered.  I created a new post for the follow-up question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449829/tableadapter-updatecommand-for-table-without-primary-key

Answer (score 0):

You can write the update sqlcommand to your DataAdapter or when you drag a table from the db he gives you the option to create the update delete and insert statements.